# Count the unread emails in exchange for each user

Tags: c#, exchange-server

i want to count the unread emails in exchange with c#
i all conected to the exchange, and get all users and the corresponding email.

for the connection i have ..

```
    RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
                PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
                PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
                Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
                myRunSpace.Open();

                Pipeline pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();
                Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Mailbox");

                pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

                Collection<PSObject> commandResults = pipeline.Invoke();

                // Ok, now we've got a bunch of mailboxes, cycle through them
                foreach (PSObject mailbox in commandResults)
                {
                    //define which properties to get
                    foreach (String propName in new string[] { "Name", "EmailAddresses", "Database", "OrganizationalUnit", "UserPrincipalName" })
                    {
                        //grab the specified property of this mailbox
                        Object objValue = mailbox.Properties[propName].Value;
.......
```

Comment: i dont kwnow how can i count the unread emails :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want is [Get-MailboxStatistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124612%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx).  You can get the Inbox_Number_Unread off the objects returned.

Glen Scales posted [this blog article](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2008/11/find-unused-mailbox-powershell-gui.html) about pulling similar information via PowerShell.  It should point you in the right direction.  It has a full script which gathers useful properties off all mailboxes.